# How to find Admin panel (CMS) for Vue Storefront

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-storefront

I'm trying to use vue storefront but one issue is that I cant access admin panel. I means if it is a complete framework there should be some views from where I can add or modify products. How can I use CRUD operations as admin and also things like entertaining orders?

Answer (score 4):

Vue Storefront is a headless solution, which means that you can connect it to any CMS (like Magento), but it is not CMS itself. You can find current CMS integrations on github: https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront or ask on the official forum: https://forum.vuestorefront.io/

Comment: can you elaborate a bit on your answer? So that it's clear for future users finding this question on what they have to do? Even when the example on githbub changes?